# low-search {auto_path} not picking up URL with sub-categories

Tags: low-search

When displaying results the the system doesn't seem to be getting the right URL for the different results.

For example is outputting

```
http://xxx.xx.dev.xx.net/blackberry-autumn-pudding
```

and the correct one is `http://xxx.xx.dev.xx.net/food/recipes/blackberry-autumn-pudding`

In another case is doing `http://ee.dev/index.php/xx-memphis-bbq-roadtrip-test` and the correct one is `http://xxx.xx.dev.xx.net/food/recipes/xx-memphis-bbq-roadtrip-test`

I guess is not picking up the categories from which that URL belongs to. How can I fix that?

```
{exp:low_search:results
                                    limit="8"
                                    query="{segment_2}"
                                    collection="article|food"
                                    status="open"
                                    keywords:inflect="yes"
                                    pagination_base="search"
                                    keywords:mode="auto"
            }

{auto_path}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the paths are set correctly in your channel preferences: http://ee2docs.com/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#search-results-url

Automatically applying categories is not possible at the moment.